# Encrypt a file in the server and decrypt it in the client without risking the user accessing it?

Tags: encryption, php, memory, python, websocket

How can I send an encrypted file from a server to a client, encrypt and use it in the client without risking the user to access it?

I saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219762/how-to-download-a-file-created-in-the-servers-memory-to-the-client-without-savi) where the server saved a file in its memory, and thought that I maybe could use the same idea but for the client. Namely, use the file directly without saving it. Although, I'm not sure if this is safe or even possible to do.

This question was orginally posted on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865779/encrypt-a-file-in-the-server-and-decrypt-it-in-the-client-without-risking-the-us) but I was told to post it here instead.

Comment: The criticism posted on SO still applies here. Your question is not specific enough. You should at least include the content of your comments there in this question and try to give us some more information about your setup.

Comment: In your question there you stated (in a comment): `the client should be able to access it but not the user`. What does that mean? Generally the client _is_ the user.

Comment: @ispiro The client will request a file from a server using sockets, to then use the file kind of as an instuction. Although, the user should not be able to see the file as it may contain sensitive information.

Comment: In that case, I generally agree with the Polynomial's answer. But if you just want to make it harder for the user (and not necessarily _impossible_) you can encrypt the information and send the encrypted information plus the key, and then decrypt it as needed. That might hide it from a non proficient non determined user.

Comment: @Qvarsken Why can't this be done on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this securely. You're running into the same problem that DRM systems do. The user owns the system, so any data that goes onto it can and will be read by a determined user no matter how many safeguards you put in place. You can put the data in memory and avoid hitting disk, but the user can just dump the process memory (Spotify's DRM was originally bypassed this way).

As an example, BluRay DRM uses High Definition Content Protection (HDCP) to prevent users from ripping content. The data on the disk is partially encrypted (only some lines in each frame get encrypted, the rest is cleartext to allow low-res playback on non-HDCP devices) and only gets decrypted by a special piece of dedicated decryption hardware in the monitor or TV, which prevents you from just capturing the HDMI output. This is a complicated end-to-end encryption scheme where the computer, BluRay player, games console, receiver, and any other intermediate hardware does not have access to the decrypted data. Regardless, a few dedicated people got together and worked out how to break HDCP and leak the decryption keys, so now you can rip the media. The same thing happened with the Xbox 360 and the PS3. Regardless of how much time and money you spend on these solutions, you're never going to beat a few dedicated researchers.

If you only need to do some very specific operations on the data (e.g. multiplication, addition, or xor) without revealing the value of the encrypted data, you could use [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption), but such schemes are largely still at an academic stage rather than something you can rely on for production systems.